# How to track which list item was clicked in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of menu options, and I need to keep track of which option was clicked. I also need to apply different style to clicked option.  Here is relevant code:

```
export default function account() {
  let [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState("username")

  const handleListItemClick = (e) => {
    let targetId = e.target.id || e.target.parentNode.id
    if (currentTab !== targetId) setCurrentTab(targetId)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <div className={styles.contentWrapper}>
          <div className={styles.leftBar}>
            <ul className={styles.listContainer}>
              <li className={`${styles.listItem} ${currentTab === "username" && styles.listItemActive} `}
                id="username"
                onClick={handleListItemClick}>
                <FiUser color="#5650bf" size="18px" />
                <span>Update username</span>
              </li>
              <li className={`${styles.listItem} ${currentTab === "topics" && styles.listItemActive} `}
                id="topics"
                onClick={handleListItemClick}>
                <FiBookmark color="#5650bf" size="18px" />
                <span>My topics</span>
              </li>
              <li className={`${styles.listItem} ${currentTab === "about" && styles.listItemActive} `}
                id="about"
                onClick={handleListItemClick}>
                <FiInfo color="#5650bf" size="18px" />
                <span>Update About page</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}
```

The code works, however, I'm not sure if it's the right way of doing it using React, and if there is a better way of solving it. Thank you.

Comment: You're doing it exactly right...I'm not sure you needed to ask this question...?

Comment: One minor tidy-up, do you need the fragment wrapping the entire return statement? It's only wrapping a single JSX element, so you could probably remove it.

Comment: @DBS it's not all code, just a relevant segment. Thank you though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than having IDs, how about just passing the name of the tab to the click callback when invoked?

Also, these sections will produce undesirable markup:

```
className={`${styles.listItem} ${currentTab === "username" && styles.listItemActive}
```

because they'll evaluate to a `className` containing `false` if the condition isn't fulfilled. Use the conditional operator so they evaluate to the empty string instead.

Change

```
<li className={`${styles.listItem} ${currentTab === "username" && styles.listItemActive} `}
  id="username"
  onClick={handleListItemClick}>
  <FiUser color="#5650bf" size="18px" />
  <span>Update username</span>
</li>
```

to

```
<li
  className={`${styles.listItem} ${currentTab === "username" ? styles.listItemActive : ''} `}
  onClick={() => setCurrentTab('username')}
>
  <FiUser color="#5650bf" size="18px" />
  <span>Update username</span>
</li>
```

No need for `handleListItemClick` - if the new state is the same as the old state, no changes will occur.

You can also abstract the class name into a function to be DRY-er:

```
const getClass = thisTab => `${styles.listItem} ${currentTab === thisTab ? styles.listItemActive : ''}`;
```

```
className={getClass('username')}
```

```
className={getClass('topics')}
```

```
className={getClass('about')}
```

Comment: Is there a performance penalty for `onClick={() => setCurrentTab('username')}` instead of doing `onClick={setCurrentTab('username')}` and having `setCurrentTab` return a callback function?

Comment: @TKoL It's possible that it'd be a smidgen slower, but it'll be absolutely insignificant, especially given that these are *individual unique* elements rather than a huge list. Better to strive for concise, readable code first.

Comment: @CertainPerformance understandable on the "individual unique elements" point. good call